# How to add a name to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

This is probably a really simple question but I am sort of confused how jQuery or JavaScript work in this way.

If I have a function for instance like this

```
$(function() {
    $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
    });
});
```

How would I write it so that I could reference it to run in html?

`<body onload="run this function()"> </body>`

I see functions written like window.onload=function() or thisFunction = function() etc.. 
and it sort of has me confused as to how a function is declared when compared to something like HTML where it is literally just div id="name" or class="name" etc..

I guess my main question is how would I get the above code to run onload in html instead of on click? Where do I title a function so that I can use it for later?

Any help on clarifying this would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

A lot of the answers i've received have ended up making more more confused and I am actually not sure what to do now.. I know I must be over thinking this but I still can't figure out how to get the site to randomize both on click and on page load.

Here is the code I have currently.

HTML

```
    <head>
        <title>Randomizer</title>
    </head>

    <body> 

         <section>

          <div>
            <video loop autoplay>
              <source src="" type="">
              <source src="" type="">
              Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
            </video>
          </div> 

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/1.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/1.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/2.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/2.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/3.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/3.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/4.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/4.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/5.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/5.mp4'}], 

];



$(function() {
    $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
    });
}); 


$(document).ready(function() { 
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length); 
     $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
 }
);
```

I was able to finally understand how it works with the above code.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: `$(function() { myFunction(); })` is basically the same as your onload. Read the `ready` docs  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: ... and then [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a function with a name for what you want to achieve (function names are mostly useful for making stacktraces in debuggers more useful than a list of a dozen *`(anonymous function)`*). You need to have a function in a variable.

---

There are four ways to create a function in JavaScript.

## Function declaration

This will create a variable `foo` in the current scope and assign a named function to it.

```
function foo () {

}
```

Function declarations are hoisted so it doesn't matter where, in the applicable scope, you put them. It is considered good coding practise to define them before you use them though.

## Anonymous function expression

This will create a function without a name and use it in an expression. In this example it is assigned to the variable `something`.

```
something = function () {

};
```

## Named function expression

This is the same as an anonymous function expression except that it has a name, creates a variable of that name in the scope of itself and is [horribly broken](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html) in older versions of Internet Explorer.

```
something = function foo () {

};
```

## Function constructor

Do not use function constructors. They are `eval` by another name. You can read about them on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) if you're interested.

---

You are currently using an anonymous function expression and passing it as a function argument (instead of assigning it to a variable as the example above does).

Just define the function separately (using any of the above techniques) and then pass the variable instead.

```
function foo(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    // etc
}

$('section').on('click', 'div', foo);
```

Watch out for scope. Declaring a function inside another function will create a local variable that you can't call globally using an intrinsic event attribute.

That said, we're approaching two decades since 1997 so you shouldn't be using intrinsic event attributes anyway.

```
$(document).on('load', foo);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the very detailed response Quentin. 

I am having some issues with the answer though, I am really not sure how to write this into my JavaScript as I have tried out your code and have had no success. I have updated my post with the code I have in, maybe you can figure out what I am doing wrong. Ultimately your answer has made me even more confused haha. Thank for you the help however

Comment: After more playing around with it I was finally able to get it to work with the above code in my recent edit. Thanks for all the help Quentin!

Answer (score 0):

Surely

```
function myname() {
    $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
    });
};
```

is required

Then

```
myname();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your code is an anonymous function. These are useful for one-time calls or for use as [callback functions](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/). For what you are trying to accomplish, you want to assign the FUNCTION REFERENCE to a variable. A function reference can be INVOKED at a later time by using parentheses, e.g. var_name()

```
var x = function(){
  // your code
}

onclick="x()"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this:

```
$(function() {
    function myFunction() {
        $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
            ...
        });
    }

    $('body').on('load', function() {
        myFunction();
    });
});
```

Placing the `onload` listener in the script like this is preferable for several reasons, such as separation of concerns, cleaner markup, etc.

That said, your original code does the same job without the `body onload` property. You don't actually need either method.

Comment: `$('body').on('load', myFunction);` - no need to introduce another anonymous function wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

To name the function you can write

```
function function_name(){
    $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
    });
};
```

Then you call it as `function_name();`

To make it run when the html is ready you write

```
$( document ).ready(
    function_name();
});
```